# how to find average of a couple of columns and make a new data set?

Tags: pandas

I have a data set how I can find the average of numerical columns for each 30 rows and make a smaller data set?

For example:

data

```
A    B     C
2.   4     f
3    1     d
4    2     p
3    1     l
2    0     g
```

Lets I wanna find the average of each 2 rows (for simplification).

```
A          B            C
(2+3)/2    (4+1)/2      d
(4+3)/2    (2+1)/2      l
2           0           g
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dividing the `index` by `n` to get groups then use [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate):

```
n = 2
new_df = df.groupby(df.index // n).agg({'A': 'mean', 'B': 'mean', 'C': 'last'})
```

`new_df`:

```
     A    B  C
0  2.5  2.5  d
1  3.5  1.5  l
2  2.0  0.0  g
```

Or the aggregation `dict` can be built programmatically by `dtype` here object dtypes are aggregated by taking the `last` value, all other types are aggregated with the `mean`:

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
aggregation_d = dict(
    zip(df.columns, np.where(df.dtypes != 'object', 'mean', 'last'))
)
new_df = df.groupby(df.index // n).agg(aggregation_d)
```

`aggregation_d`:

```
{'A': 'mean', 'B': 'mean', 'C': 'last'}
```

`new_df`:

```
     A    B  C
0  2.5  2.5  d
1  3.5  1.5  l
2  2.0  0.0  g
```

---

Explanation:

```
df.index // n
```

Creates a Series of values:

```
Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

These values establish a group.

Then the `dict` of values specifies how to aggregate each group:

```
{'A': 'mean', 'B': 'mean', 'C': 'last'}
```

Take the `mean` of `A` and `B`, and the `last` value of `C`.

Comment: I have many columns, can I skip putting the columns name one by one by another method?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how to construct the `dict` programmatically. @user15649753

Comment: `aggregation_d` was nice +1...btw `df.dtypes != 'O'` will also work